# Can I set Heroku to not retry requests on timeout by default?

Tags: heroku, request, timeout, dyno

Whenever a request times out to a dyno, it's automatically retried. Looks like it's managed by the dyno according to this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing. How can I set/change this setting myself?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to modify the behaviour of the router. If you need certain requests to be refused for whatever reason, this logic would need to be carried out within your application.

Details on how Heroku's routing works is available in the Dev Center article: [HTTP Routing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing). The section on [Dyno connection behavior on the Common Runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#dyno-connection-behavior-on-the-common-runtime) is probably most relevant to your question.

PS: This was the response of heroku support when I raised a ticket for same issue.